# split array rows into columns from commas

Tags: python, numpy

I had a list consisted of 53 3D points, I converted the list into numpy array and I have a (53,) shape array. Each row is consisted of three float points separated by commas (e.g. a_t[0]=73.72,32.27,74.95). Does anybody know how I could convert this numpy array into (53,3)? In other words, I want to split each row into three columns for each xyz coordinate.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the array is called `points` and numpy has already been imported:

```
newpoints = numpy.array([x.split(',') for x in points], dtype=numpy.float)
```

Answer (score 2):

The elements in your array are strings rather than numbers. You can loop over each row in this `(53,)` array of strings, use `split(',')` to split each row at the commas, and put the result in a new numpy array with a numeric data type:

```
 a = np.array(['1,2,3','4,5,6','7,8,9','10,11,12'])
 b = np.array([l.split(',') for l in a],dtype=np.float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone else struggling:

```
import numpy as np
newpoints = np.array([np.split(x, 3) for x in points], dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).